# Add "."(dot) in a Numbers

Tags: php

i have some numbers like this :

```
70000000
450900600
83700
```

and i want to add `.`, so it'll be :

```
70.000.000
450.900.600
83.700
```

any idea for the PHP code?

Comment: Have you tried to write any code. Besides will this be confusing with the decimal point?

Comment: then how do yo differentiate with fraction points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function,

```
$number = number_format($number, 0, '', '.');
// change 70000000 to 70.000.000 etc.

// ex. with a number set 
$numbers = array(70000000, 75000000, 300000);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo number_format($number, 0, '', '.') . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). 
4th parameter is thousands separator. You can use it to set dot to as separator.

```
$number = 450900600;
$formatted = number_format($number, 0, '', '.');

var_dump($formatted); // 450.900.600
```